# UPDATE que se realiza tras mandar el siguiente UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, update

EL problema me ocurre únicamente en el campo "entradas_disponibles".
Intento hacer un UPDATE y lo que me ocurre es lo siguiente:

Ejecuto la siguiente consulta de UPDATE:

```
UPDATE evento_lugar SET entradas_disponibles = 12 WHERE id_evento = 1;
```

Lo que sucede a continuación es que se queda con el valor anterior que tenía en la base de datos, por tanto yo interpreto que no me hace UPDATE. Pero si vuelvo a ejecutar la consulta con otro valor, por ejemplo así:

```
UPDATE evento_lugar SET evento_lugar.entradas_disponibles = 20 WHERE id_evento = 1;
```

Lo que sucede es que se actualiza pero con el valor del primer UPDATE insertadO, en este caso sería 12. Por tanto se va quedando siempre con el valor del UPDATE anterior pero sólo hasta que ejecuto la siguiente.

[image: Errores no me da en ningún momento, siempre se ejecuta correctamente pero no se me actualiza.]

Estoy ejecutando la consulta desde Mysql Workbench. Mi intención es ejecutar esta consulta desde PHP, donde me sucede lo mismo, por eso he obviado el código PHP al ver que desde Workbench tengo el mismo problema. En cambio si ejecuto esto desde el gestor phpmyadmin la consulta se ejecuta y actualiza correctamente.

La base de datos es de prueba, os dejo aquí el sql por si queréis probar a hacer la consulta. He probado en varios equipos y me sucede lo mismo.

```
  -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.6
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: localhost
-- Tiempo de generación: 04-05-2018 a las 09:10:47
-- Versión del servidor: 10.1.29-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.0

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- 
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `categoria`
--
CREATE DATABASE prueba;
use prueba;

CREATE TABLE `categoria` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `categoria`
--

INSERT INTO `categoria` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES
(3, 'Camisetas'),
(1, 'Gadgets'),
(2, 'Tazas');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `estado`
--



CREATE TABLE `estado` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `estado`
--

INSERT INTO `estado` (`id`, `nombre`) VALUES
(2, 'Aceptado'),
(1, 'Propuesto'),
(4, 'Retirado'),
(3, 'Sin existencias');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `evento`
--

CREATE TABLE `evento` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `ruta_imagen` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `evento`
--

INSERT INTO `evento` (`id`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, `ruta_imagen`) VALUES
(1, 'Coa', 'aaaaaaa', 'img/eventos/concierto1.jpg');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `evento_lugar`
--

CREATE TABLE `evento_lugar` (
  `id_evento_lugar` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_evento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_lugar` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `aforo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio_entrada` float NOT NULL,
  `entradas_disponibles` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `evento_lugar`
--

INSERT INTO `evento_lugar` (`id_evento_lugar`, `id_evento`, `id_lugar`, `fecha`, `aforo`, `precio_entrada`, `entradas_disponibles`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2018-07-18', 23, 4, 7);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `evento_participante`
--

CREATE TABLE `evento_participante` (
  `id_evento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_participante` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `evento_participante`
--

INSERT INTO `evento_participante` (`id_evento`, `id_participante`) VALUES
(1, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `fechas_posibles`
--

CREATE TABLE `fechas_posibles` (
  `id_evento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `fechas_posibles`
--

INSERT INTO `fechas_posibles` (`id_evento`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, '2018-08-23'),
(1, '2018-09-30');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `grupo`
--

CREATE TABLE `grupo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CIF` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `domicilio_fiscal` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `web` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `grupo`
--

INSERT INTO `grupo` (`id`, `CIF`, `nombre`, `domicilio_fiscal`, `web`) VALUES
(1, 51478966, 'Grupo A', 'La leira', 'algo.es');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `imagenes_prod`
--

CREATE TABLE `imagenes_prod` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_prod` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ruta` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `imagenes_prod`
--

INSERT INTO `imagenes_prod` (`id`, `id_prod`, `ruta`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'taza.jpg'),
(2, 6, 'taza2.png'),
(3, 2, 'taza3.jpeg'),
(4, 4, 'taza4.png'),
(5, 5, 'taza5.jpg'),
(6, 3, 'taza6.jpg'),
(7, 7, 'camisetanegra.jpeg'),
(11, 1, 'taza5b.jpg');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `lugar`
--

CREATE TABLE `lugar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lugar` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `lugar`
--

INSERT INTO `lugar` (`id`, `lugar`) VALUES
(1, 'Vigo');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `participante`
--

CREATE TABLE `participante` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NIF` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `apellido1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `localidad` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `grupo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `participante`
--

INSERT INTO `participante` (`id`, `NIF`, `nombre`, `apellido1`, `apellido2`, `email`, `telefono`, `direccion`, `localidad`, `provincia`, `grupo`) VALUES
(2, 53191171, 'Antonio', 'Rodriguez', 'Vega', 'antoniorodriguezvega@gmail.com', '648269348', 'C/Cortellas 56', 'Vigo', 'Pontevedra', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `producto`
--

CREATE TABLE `producto` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_fin_campana` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `producto`
--

INSERT INTO `producto` (`id`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, `categoria`, `fecha_fin_campana`) VALUES
(1, 'Taza negra', 'Taza para beber, muy cómoda y tal.', 2, '2018-08-24'),
(2, 'Taza amarilla', 'Taza para beber', 2, '2018-04-25'),
(3, 'Taza azul', 'Taza para beber', 2, '2018-04-24'),
(4, 'Taza verde', 'Taza para beber', 2, '2018-04-27'),
(5, 'Taza blanca', 'Taza para beber', 2, '2018-04-18'),
(6, 'Taza roja', 'Taza para beber', 2, '2018-04-24'),
(7, 'Camiseta Negra', 'Bonita camiseta negra para frikencios', 3, '2018-04-27');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `producto_tienda`
--

CREATE TABLE `producto_tienda` (
  `id_producto_tienda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_prod` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_tienda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` float NOT NULL,
  `estado` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `producto_tienda`
--

INSERT INTO `producto_tienda` (`id_producto_tienda`, `id_prod`, `id_tienda`, `stock`, `precio`, `estado`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 7, 4, 2),
(2, 2, 1, 30, 2.5, 2),
(3, 3, 1, 8, 1.25, 2),
(4, 4, 1, 14, 2.5, 2),
(5, 5, 1, 10, 2.5, 2),
(6, 6, 1, 17, 2.33, 2),
(7, 7, 1, 60, 15, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `reserva_event`
--

CREATE TABLE `reserva_event` (
  `id_reserva` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_evento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio_total` float NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `reserva_event`
--

INSERT INTO `reserva_event` (`id_reserva`, `id_usuario`, `id_evento`, `cantidad`, `precio_total`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 2, 120, '2018-04-11');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `reserva_prod`
--

CREATE TABLE `reserva_prod` (
  `id_reserva` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_tienda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio_total` float NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `reserva_prod`
--

INSERT INTO `reserva_prod` (`id_reserva`, `id_usuario`, `id_producto`, `id_tienda`, `cantidad`, `precio_total`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, '2018-04-18');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tienda`
--

CREATE TABLE `tienda` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `codigo_postal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tienda`
--

INSERT INTO `tienda` (`id`, `nombre`, `direccion`, `ciudad`, `codigo_postal`, `telefono`, `email`, `fax`) VALUES
(1, 'colabora Vigooo', 'Gran Via 156', '6Vigo', 362166, '9863587416', 'colaboravigo7@colaboraong.com', '9863587426');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--

CREATE TABLE `tipo_usuario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--

INSERT INTO `tipo_usuario` (`id`, `tipo`) VALUES
(1, 'Administrador'),
(2, 'Gestor'),
(3, 'Registrado');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuario`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NIF` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `localidad` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `provincia` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_sesion` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `usuario`
--

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `NIF`, `nombre`, `apellido1`, `apellido2`, `telefono`, `email`, `direccion`, `localidad`, `provincia`, `password`, `tipo`, `fecha_sesion`) VALUES
(1, '696969696', 'Jose', 'Mendez', 'Vega', '654987321', 'jose@algo.com', 'C/ Torrecedeira 6', 'Vigo', 'Pontevedra', 'renaido', 3, '2018-04-26 22:00:00');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `categoria`
--
ALTER TABLE `categoria`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `nombre` (`nombre`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `estado`
--
ALTER TABLE `estado`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `nombre` (`nombre`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `evento`
--
ALTER TABLE `evento`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `evento_lugar`
--
ALTER TABLE `evento_lugar`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_evento_lugar`),
  ADD KEY `id_evento` (`id_evento`),
  ADD KEY `id_lugar` (`id_lugar`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `evento_participante`
--
ALTER TABLE `evento_participante`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_evento`,`id_participante`),
  ADD KEY `id_participante` (`id_participante`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `fechas_posibles`
--
ALTER TABLE `fechas_posibles`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_evento`,`fecha`),
  ADD KEY `id_evento` (`id_evento`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `grupo`
--
ALTER TABLE `grupo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `CIF` (`CIF`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `imagenes_prod`
--
ALTER TABLE `imagenes_prod`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `ruta` (`ruta`),
  ADD KEY `id_prod` (`id_prod`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `lugar`
--
ALTER TABLE `lugar`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `lugar` (`lugar`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `participante`
--
ALTER TABLE `participante`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `grupo` (`grupo`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `producto`
--
ALTER TABLE `producto`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `categoria` (`categoria`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `producto_tienda`
--
ALTER TABLE `producto_tienda`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_producto_tienda`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_prod_2` (`id_prod`,`id_tienda`,`estado`),
  ADD KEY `id_prod` (`id_prod`),
  ADD KEY `id_tienda` (`id_tienda`),
  ADD KEY `estado` (`estado`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `reserva_event`
--
ALTER TABLE `reserva_event`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_reserva`),
  ADD KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`),
  ADD KEY `id_evento` (`id_evento`),
  ADD KEY `id_usuario_2` (`id_usuario`,`id_evento`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `reserva_prod`
--
ALTER TABLE `reserva_prod`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_reserva`),
  ADD KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`),
  ADD KEY `id_producto` (`id_producto`),
  ADD KEY `id_tienda` (`id_tienda`),
  ADD KEY `id_usuario_2` (`id_usuario`,`id_producto`,`id_tienda`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `tienda`
--
ALTER TABLE `tienda`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_usuario`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuario`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  ADD KEY `tipo` (`tipo`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `categoria`
--
ALTER TABLE `categoria`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `estado`
--
ALTER TABLE `estado`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `evento`
--
ALTER TABLE `evento`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `evento_lugar`
--
ALTER TABLE `evento_lugar`
  MODIFY `id_evento_lugar` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `grupo`
--
ALTER TABLE `grupo`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `imagenes_prod`
--
ALTER TABLE `imagenes_prod`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=12;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `lugar`
--
ALTER TABLE `lugar`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `participante`
--
ALTER TABLE `participante`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `producto`
--
ALTER TABLE `producto`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `producto_tienda`
--
ALTER TABLE `producto_tienda`
  MODIFY `id_producto_tienda` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `reserva_event`
--
ALTER TABLE `reserva_event`
  MODIFY `id_reserva` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `reserva_prod`
--
ALTER TABLE `reserva_prod`
  MODIFY `id_reserva` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `tienda`
--
ALTER TABLE `tienda`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_usuario`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuario`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `evento_lugar`
--
ALTER TABLE `evento_lugar`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `evento_lugar_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_evento`) REFERENCES `evento` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `evento_lugar_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_lugar`) REFERENCES `lugar` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `evento_participante`
--
ALTER TABLE `evento_participante`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `evento_participante_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_evento`) REFERENCES `evento_lugar` (`id_evento_lugar`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `evento_participante_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_participante`) REFERENCES `participante` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `fechas_posibles`
--
ALTER TABLE `fechas_posibles`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_evento` FOREIGN KEY (`id_evento`) REFERENCES `evento_lugar` (`id_evento_lugar`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `imagenes_prod`
--
ALTER TABLE `imagenes_prod`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `imagenes_prod_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_prod`) REFERENCES `producto` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `participante`
--
ALTER TABLE `participante`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `participante_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`grupo`) REFERENCES `grupo` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `producto`
--
ALTER TABLE `producto`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `producto_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`categoria`) REFERENCES `categoria` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `producto_tienda`
--
ALTER TABLE `producto_tienda`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `producto_tienda_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_prod`) REFERENCES `producto` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `producto_tienda_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tienda`) REFERENCES `tienda` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `producto_tienda_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`estado`) REFERENCES `estado` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `reserva_event`
--
ALTER TABLE `reserva_event`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `reserva_event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `reserva_event_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_evento`) REFERENCES `evento_lugar` (`id_evento_lugar`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `reserva_prod`
--
ALTER TABLE `reserva_prod`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `reserva_prod_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_producto`) REFERENCES `producto_tienda` (`id_prod`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `reserva_prod_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `reserva_prod_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tienda`) REFERENCES `producto_tienda` (`id_tienda`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuario`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usuario_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tipo`) REFERENCES `tipo_usuario` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Realmente no tiene ningún sentido lo que expones. Lo único que se me ocurre es que tengas algún problema de conexión o retardo con la base de datos o que el autocommit vaya a su bola.

Comment: Yo tampoco le encuentro el sentido, llevo desde ayer haciendo cambios en la base de datos para ver si hay algo corrupto pero no doy con ello, es absurdo y que sólo suceda con ese dato en concreto. Y he probado en 3 equipos diferentes y sucede lo mismo.

Comment: Como dice @Xerif es algo muy raro. Has probado con resetear la base de datos? Con eso me refiero a eliminarla y volver a implementarla. También preguntarte si has podido ver algún error o algo por el estilo. Y esto: `INSERT INTO `evento` (`id`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, `ruta_imagen') VALUES
(1, 'Coa', 'aaaaaaa', 'img/eventos/concierto1.jpg');` por qué usas los "acentos"? Prueba de ponerlo todo en comilla simple

Comment: Sí, he cargado de nuevo todo y nada el error persiste. Ese INSERT con esas tildes me lo genera al exportar la base de datos, copiándolo y pegándolo no hay problemas genera todo perfecto. Consultaré hoy con la persona que ha diseñado la BD y dependiendo de lo que me responda a ver si encuentro solución.

Comment: En el script que colocas tienes autocommit en 0, haz intentado hacer el query y luego ejecutar commit? seguido de hacer la consulta a ver si cambió el valor?